# Hexadecimal to Int conversion

Tags: sql, type-conversion

I am unable to connect the Hexadecimal to Int conversion.

```
 SELECT CONVERT(INT, 0x00000100) -- This statement is working

 SELECT CONVERT(int, 000000b5)   -- This is not working for me.
```

I used some hexadecimal to int conversion site. Its converting and getting result **181**.

http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter

Please let me know where i am lacking.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement should be as follows:

```
SELECT CONVERT(int, 0x000000B5)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to show that its hexadecimal number, by adding *0x* in the begginging

```
SELECT CONVERT(int, 0x000000b5)
```